# Time Machine system recovery alternative for linux

Tags: data-recovery, system-recovery

Does a Linux alternative to Time Machine (macOS) exist? I'm looking for [the recovery mode feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) that lets you restore the system completely.

Can programs like [Cronopete](https://rastersoft.com/programas/cronopete.html) or [Back in Time](https://backintime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) do that?

Comment: I use my own backup strategy, but you may want to look at [this](https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/). TimeShift is spoken of highly and has a nice GUI, as well as the ability to run from a live USB should things really go pear-shaped.

Comment: Does it need to restore from an existing time-machine file? Or are you creating new backups?

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit! :) I know my english can be messy. Thx for the link KGIII, this is exactly what I was looking for!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KGIII responded to my question in the comments by providing [this link](https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/). The software is TimeShift. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You can flush out your text that I'm responding to and then accept it as the answer, helping other people find it. By flushing it out, I mean describe why it suits your personal backup needs.

Comment: It suits my needs because I wanted to be able to completely restore my data even if my system is broken (by broken I mean impossible to boot the OS). I'm not sure if I could use this software with Debian (the tutorial asks you to boot from a live Ubuntu drive), but there may be a solution for that :) I'll have a look at this later. Again, thank you! :)