# How to make a debian backup on an external usb HDD?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, backup

I use Debian 10 on my PC (so far so good - lovin' it)- installed on a 1TB HDD (home, root, swap and EFI are separate partitions). I've installed timeshift and made some snapshots of the system, they are stored on the home partition. But I also have an old 120GB HDD from a laptop (sata3) I could use via a USB cable.
How do I go about turning it into a backup disk which (should disaster strike and my system become unbootable one day) I could just plug into the USB socket and restore my system?
If possible, could I allocate part of the disk to this function, say 20 GB and still use the remainder as portable storage for data?
Timeshift seems noob-friendly enough for me. But how do I do it? Install an OS on the 120 GB HDD? Maybe there are better options.
And I don't worry to much about the data I keep on my home partition - I wouldn't be backing that up.
I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: I like to have a full install of Ubuntu on every drive, then I use grub2's loopmount to directly boot ISO to do install onto another drive. If not regularly  using it and just installing some software you can have a full install in 20GB and use rest for data & ISO. I use Ubuntu, but Debian should be similar. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Machine system recovery alternative for linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620142/time-machine-system-recovery-alternative-for-linux)